# Why can't I add string to a Set properly?

Tags: javascript, string, set

**First example. I can't add string just writing it in `()`.**

```
let set = new Set('Emily', 'Mag');
```

[image]

Where's `'Mag'`? String is iterable, why doesn't it add to Set collection?

Comment: Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: No where in the spec does it have multiple arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the syntax is slightly off. What you might be looking for is the following:

```
let set = new Set(['Emily', 'Mag']);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Got it. Have another question. It was said that there're can be just iterable elements inside `([])`. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set#:~:text=new%20Set()-,new%20Set(iterable),-Copy%20to%20Clipboard). But it perfectly works when I'm adding Objects, numbers. Then what was meant here?

Comment: [Here](https://prnt.sc/SrKuGxNrfri6) is an example of Object and number inside `([])`

Comment: You can take a look at some iterable types in javascript here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_iterables.asp